# Custom button in UITableVIewCell overlapping images

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I have added a custom button in each cell of the UITableViewCell.That button is of type custom.I have added an image to this button.When user selects this button its image is changed. But these images of the button are overlapping.  Following is my code.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CountryCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;


}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone ;
cell.textLabel.text = [[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] wish];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

CustomWishButton *newBtn = [CustomWishButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(280,5,35,34)];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:21];
newBtn.customString = [[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] wish] ;
newBtn.customStatus = [[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] status];
newBtn.imageName = [[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]imageName];

[newBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:newBtn.imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell addSubview:newBtn];

return cell;
}

 -(void)changeStatus:(id)sender{

   CustomWishButton *resultButton= (CustomWishButton*)sender;

if ([resultButton.imageName isEqualToString:@"cancel.png"]) {

    NSString *wish = resultButton.customString;

    NSLog(@"wish: %@",wish);

    [sql updateData:wish:1:@"tick.png"];


}
else{


    NSString *wish = resultButton.customString;



    [sql updateData:wish:0:@"cancel.png"];
}

_listArray = [sql getList];

[wishTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CountryCell%d",indexPath.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            //CustomWishButton shouldn't add each and everytime! So why I kept inside.
            CustomWishButton *newBtn = [CustomWishButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(280,5,35,34)];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:21];
            newBtn.customString = [[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] wish] ;
            newBtn.customStatus = [[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] status];
            newBtn.imageName = [[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]imageName];

            [newBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:newBtn.imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [cell addSubview:newBtn];
        }

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone ;
        cell.textLabel.text = [[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] wish];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        return cell;
    }

    //instead of (id) reference I make it your CustomWishButton reference
    -(void)changeStatus:(CustomWishButton *)resultButton
    {
        if ([resultButton.imageName isEqualToString:@"cancel.png"]) 
        {
            NSString *wish = resultButton.customString;

            NSLog(@"wish: %@",wish);

            [sql updateData:wish:1:@"tick.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *wish = resultButton.customString;
            [sql updateData:wish:0:@"cancel.png"];

        }

        //Change image as per your condition
        [resultButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NewImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        _listArray = [sql getList];

        [wishTableView reloadData];
    }
```